# How i can override not exported method of module

Tags: javascript, npm, module

How i can override not exported method of NPM module?

I have a NPM module with structure like this:

```
function method (b, c) {
  ...
}

const Module = {
  install (x, y) {
    ...
    method(b, c)
    ...
  }
}

export default Module
```

Inside method with name "install" of the Module has been called method with name "method" of the NPM module.

I need override function with name "method".

Comment: you want to change the method's name from method to method?  what?

Comment: No, no, no, no... I need override function "method", not name of it.

Comment: then just re-assign the variable name to another function. what's the problem you are having?

Comment: NPM module is not mine, is only one package of the project dependencies. I need a change of that function for my purposes.

Comment: so again, re-assign the variable. obviously this requires using var instead of const when you import it.